# Data download at the beginning of the App if database is not empty

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-webview

I have made news reader App where top 20 news articles from one of the leading news websites are fetched through its API.

One activity contains listview that shows latest news titles and clicking them opens webview in other activity corresponding to that news article.

I am downloading content through AsyncTask and onPostExecute I am updating my listview. I want to do the same in OnCreate if databse is not empty.

I have tried checking if cursor.getstring(0) not null or !articlesDB.equals(null) but not working and the app crashes when opened the first time.

```
package com.example.freshnews;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    static ArrayList<String> titles=new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> articleHtml=new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> articleLinks=new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    ListView newsListView;
    String articleTitle,articleUrl,result,articleId;
    SQLiteDatabase articleDB;
    Cursor c;

    public void updateListView()

    {



        c=articleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM articles",null);
        int titleIndex=c.getColumnIndex("articleTitle");
        int codeIndex=c.getColumnIndex("articleCode");
        int linkIndex=c.getColumnIndex("articleLinks");

        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            titles.clear();
            articleHtml.clear();
            articleLinks.clear();
        }

        do {

            titles.add(c.getString(titleIndex));
            articleHtml.add(c.getString(codeIndex));
            articleLinks.add(c.getString(linkIndex));

        }while(c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            URL url;
            result="";
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;

            try {
                url = new URL(strings[0]);

                urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                int data=reader.read();

                while(data != -1)
                {
                    char current=(char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data=reader.read();
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Received article IDs

            int articleCounter;

            String newsSourceURL;

            articleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM articles");

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                if(jsonArray.length()<20)
                {
                    articleCounter=jsonArray.length();
                }
                else
                {
                    articleCounter=20;
                }



                for(int i=0;i<articleCounter;i++)
                {
                  //  Log.i("JSON Items",jsonArray.getString(i));


                    articleId=jsonArray.getString(i);
                    newsSourceURL="https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + articleId + ".json?print=pretty";
               //     Log.i("URL",newsSourceURL);

                    url=new URL(newsSourceURL);
                    urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    InputStream inputStream=urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                    int data=reader.read();

                    String articleInfo="";

                    while(data!=-1)
                    {
                        char current=(char) data;
                        articleInfo+=current;
                        data=reader.read();
                    }

                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(articleInfo);

                    if(!jsonObject.isNull("title") && !jsonObject.isNull("url")) {
                        articleTitle = jsonObject.getString("title");
                        articleUrl = jsonObject.getString("url");
                    }
                //    Log.i("Article Information",articleId + "   " + articleTitle + "   " + articleUrl);

                  /*  URL urlHtml=new URL(articleUrl);
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnectionHtml=(HttpURLConnection) urlHtml.openConnection();
                    InputStream inputStreamHtml=urlConnectionHtml.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader readerHtml=new InputStreamReader(inputStreamHtml);
                    int dataHtml=readerHtml.read();


                    while(dataHtml<50)
                    {
                        char current=(char) dataHtml;
                        articleCode+=current;
                        dataHtml=readerHtml.read();

                    }
                    Log.i("Article HTML",articleCode);*/

                    String articleCode="<html><body><h1>Hi There</h1><p>How did you find my webview?</p></body></html>";


                    String sql="INSERT INTO articles (articleId,articleTitle,articleCode,articleLinks) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

                    SQLiteStatement statement=articleDB.compileStatement(sql);
                    statement.bindString(1,articleId);
                    statement.bindString(2,articleTitle);
                    statement.bindString(3,articleCode);
                    statement.bindString(4,articleUrl);

                    statement.execute();

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            updateListView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        newsListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.newsListView);
        arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,titles);
        newsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        newsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("news",articleLinks.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        articleDB=this.openOrCreateDatabase("Articles",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        articleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, articleId INTEGER, articleTitle VARCHAR, articleCode VARCHAR, articleLinks VARCHAR) ");
       /* if(!c.moveToFirst()) {            Facing the problem here

            updateListView();
        }*/
        DownloadTask task=new DownloadTask();

        try {
            task.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty");

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: is it NullPointerException ?. Kindly share the error message

Comment: Hi, I found the solution. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

> /* if(!c.moveToFirst()) {            Facing the problem here

You would face as issue as the cursor will be null as it hasn't been instantiated.

Add the line

```
c = articleDB.rawQuery("SELECT count() FROM articles LIMIT 1",null);
```

and instead of the above you could use the more indicative :-

```
if (c.getCount() < 1) {
```